# Formatting USB drive for a MS DOS drive

Tags: usb, partitioning, ms-dos

My USB drive works when I format it with my floppy emulator. But when I format it to FAT16 with diskpart I get an error when I start up MS-DOS and the drive isn't usable. I've tried partitions below 100MB and above 100MB. Any idea on how I can fix this?

> 127MB drive = D: Not Format.

[image: Picture related]

Comment: Does not look like a diskpart screen to me.

Comment: I meant that I received the error after booting up MS-DOS. I'm having no issues with Diskpart